# MS access search button criteria cause a run time error 3075 extra

Tags: ms-access

I have a search button that searches various fields, this works well, but when i first open the form and try search, I receive  the run time error 3075 extra, but once i clear the filter, the search criteria works fine. what in the below code should I fix? SUbCategory and Stages are text

```
Private Sub cmdfilter_Click()
  Dim strWhere As String
  Dim lngLen As Long

  If Not IsNull(Me.AgencyDropDown) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([Agency] = " & Me.AgencyDropDown & ") AND "

End If

 If Not IsNull(Me.Itcleaddropdown) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([ITC Lead] = " & Me.Itcleaddropdown & ") AND "

End If


  If Not IsNull(Me.SubcatDropdown) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([Subcategory] = """ & Me.SubcatDropdown & """) AND "

End If

  If Not IsNull(Me.StageDrpdown) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([Stage] = """ & Me.StageDrpdown & """) AND "

End If

If Not IsNull(Me.ContractVehicleDropDown) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([Contract Vehicle] = " & Me.ContractVehicleDropDown & ") AND "

End If

  If Not IsNull(Me.FYdropdown) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([New FY] = " & Me.FYdropdown & ") AND "

End If

 If Not IsNull(Me.Searchdropdown) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([Opportunity Name] Like ""*" & Me.Searchdropdown & "*"") AND "

End If

 If Not IsNull(Me.SearchScopedropdown) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([Opportunity Scope] Like ""*" & Me.SearchScopedropdown & "*"") AND "

End If


 lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
    If lngLen <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "No criteria", vbInformation, "Nothing to do."
    Else
    strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)



        Me.filter = strWhere
        Me.FilterOn = True
```

[pic of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoyJe.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your dropdown values to be NULL after form opening.

In your query use `NZ()` function to replace all possible NULLs with either:

- empty string : `nz(dropdown.value,"")`
- 0 for numerics : `nz(dropdown.value,0)`

Exemple :

```
  If Not IsNull(Me.SubcatDropdown) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([Subcategory] = """ & nz(Me.SubcatDropdown,"") & """) AND "
```